# UML of an html5 indexeddb

Tags: html, uml, indexeddb

I would like to know if this is the correct UML for an indexeddb:

**DB** 1 <--  0..* **Object Store** 1 <-- 0..* **An object in the object store**

Pretty hard do draw this with characters, but i hope you get the idea. Each object store in the database can contain 0 or more objects.

ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#introduction

Comment: Whip up a diagram in Dia or some other modelling tool and link to an image sharing site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's the correct object model. One DB can have 0 or more objects stores, and same relation applies between an object in the object store.